# What is the proper way to acces a property from an object inside several scopes of a method?

Tags: javascript

For example, if I have the object:

```
function Website(){
    this.images = [];
}

Website.prototype.getImages = function(){
    jQuery('img').each(function(key, val){
        this.images.push(val.src);
    })
}
```

and I try to call `website.getImages()` I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined`

So, in order to fix this, I would do:

```
Website.prototype.getImages = function(){
    var images = this.images;
    jQuery('img').each(function(key, val){
        images.push(val.src);
    })
}
```

But I don't see this solution as clean, because what if im trying to access several variables.

Is there a cleaner and better way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of a million questions

Comment: Why instead of just whining, post a question related to this? I tried to search and didn't find any, maybe I was using the wrong words, but I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Website.prototype.getImages = function(){
    var self = this;
    jQuery('img').each(function(key, val){
        self.images.push(val.src);
        // self.someOtherProperty
        // self.someMethod()
    })
}
```

In a general sense `this` is set according to how a function is called, so as soon as you nest functions you have to do something to ensure `this` is set correctly for the inner function, e.g., `.call()` or `.apply()` - or `.bind()`, though `.bind()` isn't supported by IE until version 9.

jQuery functions that take callbacks always set `this` to something logical - in most cases the particular DOM element being processed at the time. But of course that doesn't help when you want it to be something else.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you call "clean". It's very readable. Another idea is using `.bind` which passes the `this` value, so that you can still use your first snippet:

```
jQuery('img').each(function(key, val){
    this.images.push(val.src);
}.bind(this)); // set the `this` inside `.each` to the one it is currently
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right. The reason for this behavior is that jQuery will force `this` to be each matched `<img>` on the `.each()` callback.

Comment: Even if jQuery wasn't deliberately setting `this` to each DOM element in turn, within the nested function it still wouldn't (by default) be equal to the `website` object.

Comment: Yeah, I know. The solution is the same in any case (`var that = this`).

Answer (score 0):

No, I think not. The `this` keyword it known to be set to the DOM element in almost all jQuery callback functions. Something like

```
jQuery('img').each(function(key, val){
    this.images.push(val.src);
}.bind(this));
```

would make it more messy than it must be. The "`self`" or "`that`" dereferencing-variable is the standard way to do this. However, you could easily do without jQuery:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i=0, l=imgs.length; i<l; i++)
    this.images.push(imgs[i].src);
```

...which is a line shorter, faster than jQuery and working cross-browser as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use jQuery.proxy. Its basically a wrapper for the Function.bind function that others have mentioned. Except that it works in all browsers.

```
Website.prototype.getImages = function(){
    jQuery('img').each(
        jQuery.proxy(function(key, val){
            // 'this' now refers to the instance of Website
            this.images.push(val.src);
            this.other_property = 'awesome';
        }, this)
    );
}
```